# Thread safe coding by using lock statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I am having some doubts while using [`lock statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspxlock) to make thread safe, here is my code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public ClassName _Obj;
    private static object LockObj = new object();

    public ClassName Obj
    {
        get { return _Obj ?? (_Obj = new ClassName()); }
    }

    public void ThreadA()
    {
        //lock (LockObj) --able to handle the thread
        //lock (Obj) --it is also able to handle the thread
        lock (this) // --same for this also
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Obj.ValueA = i;
                // Processing on Obj..
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ClassName
{
    public int ValueA { get; set; }
}
```

In this block of code `ThreadA` can be made safe by using a `lock` statement. But which is the exact way of passing an argument to the lock statement? The same result can be achieved by passing `ClassName` object i.e `Obj`, `LockObj` object which is static or by `this` object also. Please make it clear, which is better and why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Tip: use `public static readonly object LockObj = new object();` since the `readonly` will prevent anyone from creating a new lock object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to explain `lock` statement:

> In general, avoid locking on a public type, or instances beyond your
>   code's control. The common constructs lock (this), lock (typeof
>   (MyType)), and lock ("myLock") violate this guideline:
>
> - lock (this) is a problem if the instance can be accessed publicly.
> - lock (typeof (MyType)) is a problem if MyType is publicly accessible.
> - lock("myLock") is a problem because any other code in the process    using the same string, will share the same lock.
>
> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private
>   static object variable to protect data common to all instances.